# Can't scroll weekCalendar to next/prev month react-native-calendar

Tags: react-native, calendar

I cant scroll pre/next month in this week-calendar of react-native-calendar , It seem to back pre week instead of go to next month

```
<WeekCalendar
                                hideDayNames={true}
                                firstDay={1}
                                dayComponent={this.renderDate}
                                theme={calendarThemes}
                                allowShadow={false}
                                markedDates={{
                                    ...this.state.markedDates,
                                    [this.state.selectedDate.dateString]: {
                                        selected: true,
                                    },
                                }}
                                pastScrollRange={(new Date().getFullYear() - 1900) * 12}
                                futureScrollRange={(2099 - new Date().getFullYear()) * 12}
                                current={this.state.selectedDate}
                                onDayPress={(date) => this.changeDate(date.dateString)} />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

must wrap with CalendarProvider

```
<CalendarProvider
                                date={this.state.selectedDate.dateString}
                                onDateChanged={this.onDateChanged}
                                markedDates={{
                                    ...this.state.markedDates,
                                    [this.state.selectedDate.dateString]: {
                                        selected: true,
                                    },
                                }}
                            >
                                <WeekCalendar
                                    firstDay={1}
                                    calendarWidth={screenWidth}
                                    allowShadow={false}
                                    markedDates={{
                                        ...this.state.markedDates,
                                        [this.state.selectedDate.dateString]: {
                                            selected: true,
                                        },
                                    }}
                                    pastScrollRange={(new Date().getFullYear() - 1900) * 12}
                                    futureScrollRange={(2099 - new Date().getFullYear()) * 12}
                                    style={[ { paddingBottom: 20, paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0 }]}
                                />
```